# Change y axis labs from decimals to percentage

Tags: r

I would like to convert the numbers in the z axis from 0.4 to 40%.

that is the code I am using but I ca not figure out a way without using ggplot.

```
growth <- plot(x = dfinvtprop$fyear, y = dfinvtprop$ratio, type="l", lty=2, lwd=3, col="darkgrey", xlab="Year", cex.lab =2, cex.main = 1.5, ylab="As % of total assets", cex.axis= 1.5, main = "A: Various assets as % of total assets", ylim= c(0, 0.65),  xlim=c(1980,2020))+
  lines(x = dfacqprop$fyear, y= dfacqprop$ratio, lwd=3, type="l", col="black")+
  lines(x = dfotherinttprop$fyear, y = dfotherinttprop$ratio, type="l", lty=4, lwd=3, col="black")+
  text(x=1988, y=0.4, labels= "Productive assets", col = "darkgrey", cex = 2) +
  text( x=2010, y=0.18, label=  "Goodwill" , col = "black", cex = 2) +
  text( x=2013, y=0.06, label= "Intangible", col = "black", cex = 2) +
  text(x = 2013, y=0.025, label= "(excl. Goodwill)", col = "black", cex = 2)
```

Here is a photo of the graph:

[image]

Comment: You are trying to mix base R plotting function  with `ggplot`  syntax  (+) which is a no-go. If you prefer sticking with base R plotting and want to convert the y-axis labels to percentages, you can use `axis()` to customize the axis labels.

Comment: The secret here is to specify no axis by adding `yaxt = 'n'` inside `plot`. Then add the y axis manually using `axis(2, at = seq(0, 0.6, 0.1), lab = paste0(0:6 * 10, '%'))`. In any case, the question is a duplicate. Please see the linked duplicate for a more complete exposition.